# PowerShell XML preserve indentation

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and tried to write a script that edits a xml-file by simply adding and removing (that part is still missing) depending on whether the line is or isn't already present.
Yet I've accomplished to successfully add the line in the right position. But upon saving the xml after adding the line the indent somehow is broken/transformed into 2 whitespaces.
$xml.PreserveWhiteSpace = $true fully breaks the formatting by deleting all the line breaks.
I also tried XmlWriter which seems to be crashing in background blocking the file for further editing until next reboot.

Here is my original xml-content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Application>
        <LastUsedFile>
            <Path></Path>
            <CredProtMode>Obf</CredProtMode>
            <CredSaveMode>NoSave</CredSaveMode>
        </LastUsedFile>
    </Application>
</Configuration>
```

That's how it should look like (new element LanguageFile before LastUsedFile):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Application>
        <LanguageFile>German.lngx</LanguageFile>
        <LastUsedFile>
            <Path></Path>
            <CredProtMode>Obf</CredProtMode>
            <CredSaveMode>NoSave</CredSaveMode>
        </LastUsedFile>
    </Application>
</Configuration>
```

This is what I'm actually receiving upon saving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Application>
    <LanguageFile>German.lngx</LanguageFile>
    <LastUsedFile>
      <Path></Path>
      <CredProtMode>Obf</CredProtMode>
      <CredSaveMode>NoSave</CredSaveMode>
    </LastUsedFile>
</Configuration>
```

Buy using that code:

```
$path = "$env:APPDATA\App"
$file = "$env:APPDATA\App\App.config.xml"
$NodeExists = $null

if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path))
    {
        Write-Output "$path existiert."
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($file))
            {
                Write-Output "$file existiert."
                $xml = [XML](Get-Content $file)
                $application = $xml.Configuration.Application
                $NodeExists = $xml.Configuration.Application.LanguageFile
                Write-Output $NodeExists
                if(!$NodeExists)
                    {
                        $langelem = $xml.CreateElement('LanguageFile')
                        $langtext = $xml.CreateTextNode('German.lngx')
                        $langelem.AppendChild($langtext)
                        $application.InsertBefore($langelem, $application.FirstChild)
                        Write-Output "Sprache auf Deutsch gestellt."
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Write-Output "Sprache ist auf Deutsch gesetzt."
                        $application.RemoveChild($application.FirstChild)
                        Write-Output "Sprache auf Englisch gestellt."                       
                    }
                $xml.Save($file)
            }
        else
            {
                Write-Output "$file existiert NICHT."
            }
    }
else
    {
        Write-Output "$path existiert NICHT."
    }
```

Comment: Why does it even matter whether the XML is indented by 2 or 4 spaces?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point. Eddga if it's for esthetics, see [this function](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/powershell-tip-use-xml-indentation-to-make-it-more-readable/)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I guess it doesn't, but I wanted to keep the file in its original state as much as possible. Dunno if this transformation somehow could break the function of the program that uses this config. Apart from that I'm more likely to ask why the script even causes that issue?

Comment: @LotPings How would I use that script for saving? Looks like being intended for use with the console? (Again: sorry I'm new to PS)

Comment: It is a function what you suppy to it and what you do with the output is up to you, pipe it somwhere evt. to `|Set-Content file.xml -Encoding Utf8`

Comment: @LotPings using the following line instead of the .save-function:  
`IndentXML -Content $xml -Indent 4 | Set-Content $file -Encoding Utf8`
Works properly and somehow does what I wanted to achieve. Anyway - why are the tab chars replaced with spaces at all?

Comment: Adding `$xmlWriter.IndentChar = "\`t"` to the function also brought tab chars instead of spaces back. :) Issue seems to be fully addressed now. Still wondering why this is necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @LotPings with a hint to [that function](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/powershell-tip-use-xml-indentation-to-make-it-more-readable/) brought the solution. Adding

```
$xmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
```

to the function fully recovered the original formatting of the xml. So now it's more like recovering the indentation instead of preserving it in the first place. This is the full working code including the function:

```
$path = "$env:APPDATA\App"
$file = "$env:APPDATA\App\App.config.xml"
$NodeExists = $null

Function Format-XMLIndent
{
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias("IndentXML")]
    param
    (
        [xml]$Content,
        [int]$Indent
    )

    # String Writer and XML Writer objects to write XML to string
    $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter 
    $XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter 

    # Default = None, change Formatting to Indented
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented" 

    # Gets or sets how many IndentChars to write for each level in 
    # the hierarchy when Formatting is set to Formatting.Indented
    $xmlWriter.Indentation = $Indent
    $xmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"

    $Content.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter) 
    $XmlWriter.Flush();$StringWriter.Flush() 
    $StringWriter.ToString()
}

if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path))
    {
        Write-Output "$path existiert."
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($file))
            {
                Write-Output "$file existiert."
                $xml = [XML](Get-Content $file)
                $application = $xml.Configuration.Application
                $NodeExists = $xml.Configuration.Application.LanguageFile
                Write-Output $NodeExists
                if(!$NodeExists)
                    {
                        $langelem = $xml.CreateElement('LanguageFile')
                        $langtext = $xml.CreateTextNode('German.lngx')
                        $langelem.AppendChild($langtext)
                        $application.InsertBefore($langelem, $application.FirstChild)
                        Write-Output "Sprache auf Deutsch gestellt."
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Write-Output "Sprache ist auf Deutsch gesetzt."
                        $application.RemoveChild($application.FirstChild)
                        Write-Output "Sprache auf Englisch gestellt."                       
                    }
                IndentXML -Content $xml -Indent 1 | Set-Content $file -Encoding Utf8
            }
        else
            {
                Write-Output "$file existiert NICHT."
            }
    }
else
    {
        Write-Output "$path existiert NICHT."
    }
```